# Selenium: Opening elements on new window c#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using chrome and selenium.
My code supposes to do open a link, and on that link, it supposes to open other clickable items on the new page. For this, I created an action. When it `k==4`, it opens a new window, doing something and closes driver. `Action` that I wrote, only works for once. When `k==5`, it uses the main driver and closes the main driver as well.

```
for (int k = 4; k < 100; k++) // i do not know how many elements contain
{
    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        Actions action = new Actions(secondDriver);
        IWebElement linkInbox = secondDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(element));
        action.KeyDown(Keys.Shift).Click(linkInbox).Perform();
        secondDriver.SwitchTo().Window(secondDriver.WindowHandles.Last());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    secondDriver.Close();
    secondDriver.SwitchTo().Window(secondDriver.WindowHandles.First());
}
```

EDIT 1: Instead of using actions, Is there any `Ijavascriptexecutor` solution?

Comment: Can it open the new window? What is the error?

Comment: @Buaban it works only for 1 once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to store the `CurrentWindowHandle` and use it when you want to switch back.  As for the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>, I think you'd better use JSExecutor to add an attribute `target='_blank'` to the link before you click on it.

```
string mainWindowHandle = secondDriver.CurrentWindowHandle;
for (int k = 4; k < 100; k++) // i do not know how many elements contain
{
  try
  {
    Thread.Sleep(300);
    IWebElement linkInbox = secondDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(element));
    var script = "arguments[0].setAttribute('target','_blank');"
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)secondDriver).ExecuteScript(script, linkInbox);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    linkInbox.Click();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    secondDriver.SwitchTo().Window(secondDriver.WindowHandles.Last());
    // do the thing here

    Thread.Sleep(500);
    secondDriver.Close();
    secondDriver.SwitchTo().Window(mainWindowHandle);
  catch (Exception)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(500);
  }
  if(secondDriver.WindowHandles.Count()>1)
  {
    secondDriver.SwitchTo().Window(secondDriver.WindowHandles.Last()).Close();
    secondDriver.SwitchTo().Window(mainWindowHandle);
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried it. It gives the same result, it works for only ones. Do you think, should I also hold the second window as well?

Comment: I've updated the answer. I think there is an error in try so it uses the main window in the next loop.